# How to use Gnus with newsgroup like Google Group?

Tags: emacs, gnus

I tried this setting:

```
(setq gnus-select-method '(nnml "comp.lang.lisp"))
```

But when I activate Gnus, no grouop is shown. How do I add groups like `comp.lang.*`?

Edit: I tried with nntp:

`(setq gnus-select-method '(nntp "comp.lang.lisp"))`

but it doesn't work:

`Warning: Opening nntp server on comp.lang.lisp...failed: ; Server nntp+comp.lang.lisp previously determined to be down; not retrying`

Comment: `nnml` is a select method that stores messages in a directory on the local disk.  I guess you want the `nntp` method instead, which connects to a news server using the NNTP protocol.

Comment: I've just tried the `nntp` but got the error: `Warning: Opening nntp server on comp.lang.lisp...failed: ; Server nntp+comp.lang.lisp previously determined to be down; not retrying`

Comment: Right, the string after `nntp` needs to be the hostname of an NNTP server.  You could use http://www.eternal-september.org/ (registration required).

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Expanding on @logoscia's comment, *comp.lang.lisp* isn't an NNTP server, but a newsgroup.  You can use [Gmane/Gwene](http://gmane.org/) to read mailing lists and RSS feeds via NNTP.  You can also add a traditional news server, like news.eternal-september.org.  The elisp snippet below can get you started.

```
(setq gnus-select-method '(nnml "")) ;; this depends on how you want
                                     ;; to get your mail
(setq gnus-secondary-select-methods '((nntp "news.gmane.org")
                                      (nntp "news.eternal-september.org")))
```

Start Gnus with `M-x gnus`.  In the group buffer hit `^` to get to the *Server* buffer then browse the newsgroups on the servers.  From there you can subscribe/unsubscribe to newsgroups with `u`.  Back in the *Group* buffer you will see your subscribed groups.  For details, see [the Gnus manual](http://www.gnus.org/manual.html).

Comment: I'm not allowed to register at Eternal September (tried 5 email addresses).  Is that the only news server besides Gmane?  I like reading content through Gnus, but for most NNTP servers you need to pay a monthly (!) fee + their websites and registration process look super shady.

Comment: Hmm.. The NNTP server is alive.  Some pages behind the main page like http://gmane.org/about are up.  On that page it says something about churn related to a recent move.  You can read more about that move at https://lars.ingebrigtsen.no/2016/07/28/the-end-of-gmane/.